# Unable to change Date Format

Tags: android, date

I want to change date format like 22-Jan'14.My code give output  14-Jan-22 this format.
How can I change it.

```
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yy-MMM-dd");
        java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
        String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use below code. There is a mistake in your date format. You want output as date, month and year and you are passing year, month and date. So change as below

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
String datetime = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Just change format of your date from `("yy-MMM-dd")` to `("dd-MMM-yy")`

Comment: i did but i want to 22-Jan'14 and your code show 22-jan-14

Comment: i tried  but it throws exception

Comment: It solve by split date string

Comment: Good, Finally glad to hear that you have achieved what you want.  +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
String dtStart = "11/08/2013 08:48:10";
    SSimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
    try {
        date = format.parse(dtStart);
        System.out.println("Date ->" + date);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: my code give me output like 14'Jan-22 but i want year last ex:22-Jan'14

Answer (score 0):

```
String date = "2011/11/12 16:05:06";
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:MM:SS");
        Date testDate = null;
        try {
            testDate = sdf.parse(date);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
        String newFormat = formatter.format(testDate);
        System.out.println(".....Date..."+newFormat);
```

Comment: i want to ***22-Jan'14** not 11/12/2011 16:05:06